# Parsing json var inside script tag

Tags: python, lxml

I'm currently trying to scrape the json output of the follow `'https://sports.bovada.lv/soccer/premier-league'`

it has a source with the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">var swc_market_lists = {"items":[{"description":"Game Lines","id":"23", ... </script>
```

I'm trying to get the contents of the `swc_market_lists` var

Now the issue I have is that when I use the following code

```
import requests
from lxml import html



url = 'https://sports.bovada.lv/soccer/premier-league'
r = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
var = tree.xpath('//script')
print(var)
```

I get an empty var value.

I have also tried saving the `r.text` and viewing it but I don't see the script tags in there.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass the `User-Agent` header to make it work:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36"})
```

To get the desired `script`, you can check for presence of `swc_market_lists` in the text:

```
script = tree.xpath('//script[contains(., "swc_market_lists")]/text()')[0]
print(script)
```

To extract the `swc_market_lists` variable value:

```
import re

data = re.search(r"var swc_market_lists = (.*?);$", script).group(1)
print(data)
```

Then, to make it easy to work with it, load it with `json.loads()` into a Python dictionary:

```
import json
data = json.loads(data)
```