# How to get information from the html script below?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I extracted the following script from html using beautiful-soup:

```
<script>
   dataLayer =[{
  "pageTitle": "PRODUCT: Macculloch Parka Print( 9512MP )",
  "pageCategory": "shop-mens-parkas",
  "visitorLoginState": "Guest",
  "EmployeeLoginState": false,
  "customerEmail": "null",
  "customerOrders": "null",
  "customerValue": "0",
  "Country": "CA",
  "State": "ON",
  "ecommerce": {
    "currencyCode": "CAD",
    "detail": {
      "actionField": {
        "list": "Product Category / Search Results"
         },

      "products": [
        {
          "name": "Macculloch Parka Print",
          "id": "9512MP",
          "price": 1295,
          "brand": "Canada Goose",
          "category": "shop-mens-parkas"}]}}}];</script>
```

I want to extract the information related to the product (name, id, price and brand) as a dataframe. Is there a way to do it without using regex?

Comment: That data looks like JSON, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing json var inside script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306761/parsing-json-var-inside-script-tag). I don't believe there is a way to do this without using regex unfortunately.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile - its not JSON though.

Comment: @soom It’s just a JS array of dicts, right? I don’t know why I asked if it was JSON lol

Comment: @AlexanderCécile yes, an array of dicts

Comment: @soom Did you ever figure this out, or are you still looking/awaiting answers?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, not yet. I have used regex for now but I was looking for efficient ways to do it

Comment: @soom Is the format always the same? The JSON will always be inside of a list, assigned to a var named `dataLayer`, etc.? Also, can you provide some more information on the program as a whole? Where is this HTML coming from, for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` to get json and parse:

```
import json
import re

data = json.loads(re.search(r"dataLayer =(.*);", d, re.DOTALL).group(1))
products = data[0]["ecommerce"]["detail"]["products"]
product_name = products[0]["name"]
product_id = products[0]["id"]
product_price = products[0]["price"]
product_brand = products[0]["brand"]
product_category = products[0]["category"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a temporary solution, contingent on receiving more information on the format of the data.

```py
import re
import json

def get_datalayer_json(raw_script_tag: str):
    parser_re = r"<script>\s*dataLayer =(.*);\s*</script>"
    parser_result = re.match(parser_re, raw_script_tag.strip(), re.DOTALL)
    if parser_result is None:
        return None
    else:
        return json.loads(parser_result.group(1))
```