# Loop through URL in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to analyze hotels from Tripadvisor for the Hotel chain Melia at Spain.
Having made a selection of 35 hotels, we wanted to use a code that enables us to create a dataframe looping through the Urls instead of going one by one manually.

We created the base code, which includes the info we want for one of the hotels. (Copied below)
However, although getting the url of the session is a possibility, our selection is more "random" and it is not one of the webpage categories (for example they have a category which is Hotels in Spain, but there is not a list for our hotels). Do you know some way to achieve that?

*Scraping Bubbles*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTRQ9.png)

We do cannot get the code for the stars. Here is what we used before the script, and the script we found.

```
url2 <- "https://www.tripadvisor.es/Hotel_Review-g187499-d239247-Reviews-Melia_Girona-Girona_Province_of_Girona_Catalonia.html"
TripHotel<-read_html(url2)

Estrellas <- TripHotel %>%
  html_nodes("_2TmwtWEr _30WZSV_9 uq1qMUbD") %>%
  html_text()
Estrellas


The script we get for StarRating is window._WEB_CONTEXT_={pageManifest:{"assets":["/components/dist/@ta/platform.polyfill-web-minimal.8629eb7b79.js","/components/dist/runtime.fe87536ca9.js","/components/dist/@ta/platform.runtime.e329407de2.js","/components/dist/vendor-babel.d45f1e0c4b.js","/components/dist/vendor-react-libs.7a36afd64a.js","/components/dist/vendor-redux-libs.aa893c3e8e.js","/components/dist/ta-platform.69750d80c2.js","/components/dist/lithium-platform.96ba6a9bc0.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.features.2a6979d658.js","/components/dist/@ta/platform.sentry.8f209cb2ac.js","/components/dist/@ta/platform.interactions.79fdeef568.js","/components/dist/vendor-apollo-libs.47c5785823.js","/components/dist/vendor-common.14a97ab607.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.responsive.4c9b587da5.js","/components/dist/lithium-routes.ea28cf22de.js","/components/dist/@ta/platform.monikers.cbbb67e0e2.js","/components/dist/@ta/core-ui.toast.d06b307144.js","/components/dist/@ta/platform.ssr-cache.49252e32a2.js","/components/dist/@ta/login.auth-gate-original.ef5977ab0d.js","/components/dist/@ta/login.auth-gate-lithium.43308c8956.js","/components/dist/@ta/login.login.b2621e9aa7.js","/components/dist/lithium-common.8e2735e535.js","/components/dist/vendor-urql.c12714ee06.js","/components/dist/vendor-lodash-libs.5c5eb190c8.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.object-util.c3bc3badfd.js","/components/dist/tslib.e90a942e35.js","/components/dist/vendor-react-dom-server.ce31892dfe.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.transitions.34c0d6a9f3.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.webview.3291fba6a5.js","/components/dist/@ta/modal.styleguide.7be39367d0.js","/components/dist/@ta/events.window.e20a52ae75.js","/components/dist/ta-common.b8bb120511.js","/components/dist/@ta/overlays.popover.085dd7b789.js","/components/dist/@ta/modal.fullscreen.21e9eb7e09.js","/components/dist/@ta/modal.vanilla.13e6154218.js","/components/dist/@ta/input.drop-zone.7afa95149d.js","/components/dist/@ta/media-viewer.types.6010627a44.js","/components/dist/react-transition-group.bdcd384ecd.js","/components/dist/@ta/overlays.pieces.31662725af.js","/components/dist/@ta/overlays.attached-arrow-overlay.b8013ac42f.js","/components/dist/@ta/modal.core.1d1febe0c4.js","/components/dist/@ta/overlays.attached-overlay.9f19a478e2.js","/components/dist/@ta/overlays.shift.63c6c0d933.js","/components/dist/@ta/events.keyboard-event-listener.cf353a32be.js","/components/dist/@ta/a11y.focus.b656b98684.js","/components/dist/@ta/events.window-resize.e97c27ed34.js","/components/dist/@ta/platform.runtime.e7e9ab5e5c.css","/components/dist/ta-platform.f5afcf1468.css","/components/dist/@ta/platform.monikers.80f1d43c6e.css","/components/dist/@ta/core-ui.toast.4dc70a9cf8.css","/components/dist/@ta/login.auth-gate-lithium.59bf39748e.css","/components/dist/lithium-common.a4449756a1.css","/components/dist/@ta/common.webview.dd67304f49.css","/components/dist/ta-common.fa2b80cda8.css","/components/dist/@ta/overlays.popover.bc2c0648bc.css","/components/dist/@ta/modal.fullscreen.a01c6b7342.css","/components/dist/@ta/modal.vanilla.dc35b80706.css","/components/dist/@ta/input.drop-zone.a2a1035b2d.css","/components/dist/@ta/overlays.pieces.5252ffa89a.css","/components/dist/@ta/modal.core.15bfe91f4f.css","/components/dist/t4b.t4b-header.beca207473.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.data-cacher.6b1422d012.js","/components/dist/@ta/t4b.fullstory.ad384c9af1.js","/components/dist/@ta/hrm.qualaroo-survey.dc06f3d1e6.js","/components/dist/@ta/hrm.subscription-utils.3f8a85d442.js","/components/dist/t4b.t4b-header.41189e4309.css","/components/dist/t4b.t4b-header-mw.77987e5a99.js","/components/dist/@ta/overlays.slide-in.54e1061c97.js","/components/dist/@ta/modal.slide-in.6be2335380.js","/components/dist/t4b.t4b-header-mw.a02bc6e3ad.css","/components/dist/@ta/modal.slide-in.bd9d180953.css","/components/dist/@ta/brand.footer.0ffbbc5cbd.js","/components/dist/@ta/core-ui.responsive-container.d2340afaf7.js","/components/dist/@ta/core-ui.link.cad10f6ef5.js","/components/dist/@ta/cpm.consent-mgmt.5505c307af.js","/components/dist/@ta/overlays.responsive-attached-overlay.6a62c30680.js","/components/dist/@ta/modal.headers.883409ed29.js","/components/dist/@ta/brand.breadcrumbs.4facfa91e7.js","/components/dist/@ta/seo.on-page-factors.6a471f02c0.js","/components/dist/@ta/cpm.universal-consent-platform-loader.d52599cc36.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.breadcrumbs.7bfa701f29.js","/components/dist/@ta/brand.nav-links.6459b150b0.js","/components/dist/@ta/brand.context.0db13f31d7.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.json-ld.cdce1b4d51.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.obfuscated-link.971bde5bac.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.text-html.432c62dc8c.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.client.e7412d80a4.js","/components/dist/@ta/brand.footer.eba6478b2c.css","/components/dist/@ta/core-ui.responsive-container.6a3e9d8142.css","/components/dist/@ta/core-ui.link.0f5c30e3f8.css","/components/dist/@ta/modal.headers.b268aa40c7.css","/components/dist/@ta/brand.breadcrumbs.7afc981777.css","/components/dist/@ta/common.breadcrumbs.a00e58e432.css","/components/dist/@ta/common.obfuscated-link.a0e0d02491.css","/components/dist/@ta/hotels.hr-about-amenities.9b050ed5d6.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.ssronly.e4be79bac9.js","/components/dist/@ta/styleguide.skeleton.b5edd4f833.js","/components/dist/@ta/hotels.hr-about-layout.454cd75b1c.js","/components/dist/@ta/styleguide.grouping-tabs.0c0c441774.js","/components/dist/@ta/hotels.tags.5bba931453.js","/components/dist/@ta/hotels.hr-about-amenities.40faf03e31.css","/components/dist/@ta/styleguide.skeleton.9ef3c38c68.css","/components/dist/@ta/hotels.hr-about-layout.49df83afe1.css","/components/dist/@ta/styleguide.grouping-tabs.38225b9733.css","/components/dist/brand.header/LithiumGlobalNavWrapper.demand.a8d9d8e6ba.js","/components/dist/@ta/brand.header.2b51087b14.js","/components/dist/@ta/brand.global-nav.02e9fa460e.js","/components/dist/@ta/core-ui.avatar.223f2ac085.js","/components/dist/@ta/memx.explicit-preferences-lithium.a313781717.js","/components/dist/@ta/onboarding.explicit-preferences-external-tracking.d784e24e65.js","/components/dist/@ta/brand.sponsored-geopill.c829aea775.js","/components/dist/@ta/search.typeahead.d08803f3ee.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.hover-chain.27bdc86591.js","/components/dist/@ta/styleguide.nav-tabs.77f1cb9ccb.js","/components/dist/@ta/memx.attr-promo-screen.5f64728279.js","/components/dist/@ta/onboarding.common.1d6a1bf224.js","/components/dist/@ta/onboarding.text-input.c9b9ad73f7.js","/components/dist/@ta/cpm.y8p4bb.01610be7f6.js","/components/dist/@ta/platform.routing.2a83cbc988.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.sessionstorage.91e1dbe02e.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.localstorage.a16fd2c438.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.typeahead.16ded082ae.js","/components/dist/@ta/list.navigable-list.3d2c6813ec.js","/components/dist/@ta/cpm.gpt-slots-controller.58f3976be7.js","/components/dist/@ta/cpm.rubicon-header-bidding.8f9f909334.js","/components/dist/@ta/events.window-visibility.91a17522ae.js","/components/dist/@ta/cpm.utils.45611a3edb.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.keyboardCodes.b2e4a5f8ad.js","/components/dist/@ta/input.text-input.2ab20c2563.js","/components/dist/@ta/cpm.adomik-slot-params.fe9b20aa6b.js","/components/dist/brand.header/LithiumGlobalNavWrapper.demand.a557b85179.css","/components/dist/@ta/brand.header.08133f1070.css","/components/dist/@ta/brand.global-nav.59fa1be068.css","/components/dist/@ta/core-ui.avatar.84d9d7bfb8.css","/components/dist/@ta/memx.explicit-preferences-lithium.f9d958fcd2.css","/components/dist/@ta/search.typeahead.1a69e046ec.css","/components/dist/@ta/memx.attr-promo-screen.e1370082f6.css","/components/dist/@ta/onboarding.common.e025519e12.css","/components/dist/@ta/onboarding.text-input.a91711d401.css","/components/dist/@ta/cpm.y8p4bb.d15f5fa775.css","/components/dist/@ta/common.typeahead.9453bd61be.css","/components/dist/@ta/input.text-input.948597fce8.css","/components/dist/@ta/hotels.hr-about-partial-match-filters.5157516ea8.js","/components/dist/@ta/hotels.hr-about-partial-match-filters.f4af8d1c27.css","/components/dist/@ta/hotels.hotel-review-about-csr.706b3fa8d2.js","/components/dist/@ta/overlays.tooltip.d87c721909.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.ajax.fbfa19c52b.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.text.b9ff6f2848.js","/components/dist/@ta/hotels.partner-content-shared-components.6a5a8fa946.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.photo-carousel.2abbd26e14.js","/components/dist/@ta/hotels.media-album-parts.268c77863a.js","/components/dist/@ta/media-viewer.opener.61bfb36637.js","/components/dist/@ta/business-advantage.use-hotel-travel-info.3c53e0b232.js","/components/dist/@ta/public.business-listing.dd1cc04579.js","/components/dist/@ta/hotels.hotel-offers.01b5407a3b.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.polygon.b15ea13de1.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.loadable.fd63e87a36.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.indicator-dots.dd848da747.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.accumulating-provider.834c99a063.js","/components/dist/@ta/public.graphql-util.618d630be3.js","/components/dist/@ta/hotels.media-album-configuration.cd0d532a86.js","/components/dist/@ta/media.metrics.c624a57f8e.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.cookie.35892691a9.js","/components/dist/@ta/media-viewer.hash-utils.e7e7fd1e02.js","/components/dist/@ta/media-viewer.tracking.03ca8bde05.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.dates.ea8681abcb.js","/components/dist/@ta/business-advantage.special-offer-lightbox.3408f3a4f5.js","/components/dist/@ta/overlays.modal.1061eb3223.js","/components/dist/@ta/public.dataroots.c36e49c3fc.js","/components/dist/@ta/public.data-api-polling.a11e0ebf6b.js","/components/dist/@ta/common.metrics.3e79a9ec7c.js","/components/dist/@ta/business-advantage.special-offer-lightbox-overlay.9bbb115255.js","/components/dist/@ta/business-advantage.special-offer-details-provider.bf58636ab5.js","/components/dist/@ta/business-advantage.special-offer-carousel.bac746ea9f.js","/components/dist/@ta/business-advantage.carousel.08ab0fcd2e.js","…
```

*Latitude and Longitude*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImvzD.png)

Here we get the location but we cannot obtain neither the longitude or latitude.

*UPDATED CODE*

"Error in data.frame(Hotel = Hotel, Location = Location, OverallRating = OverallRating,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0"

```
   getwd()
# Limpiamos la consola
cat("\014")

library(rvest)
library(plyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

url2 <- "https://www.tripadvisor.es/Hotel_Review-g187499-d239247-Reviews-Melia_Girona-Girona_Province_of_Girona_Catalonia.html"
TripHotel<-read_html(url2)

getHotel <- function(TripHotel){
Hotel <- TripHotel %>%
  html_node(".masthead_h1") %>%
  html_text()
Hotel


TotalReviews <- TripHotel %>%
  html_nodes(".hotels-hotel-review-atf-info-parts-Rating__reviewCount--1sk1X") %>%
  html_text()
TotalReviews


Location <- TripHotel %>%
  html_nodes(".hotels-hotel-review-atf-info-parts-BusinessListingEntry__address--1Vy86") %>%
  html_text()
Location

OverallRating <- TripHotel %>%
  html_nodes(".hotels-hotel-review-about-with-photos-Reviews__overallRating--vElGA") %>%
  html_text()
  as.numeric()
OverallRating

ratingText <- TripHotel %>%
  html_nodes(".hotels-hotel-review-about-with-photos-Reviews__subratingRow--2u0CJ") %>%
  html_text()
ratingText

nodes <- read_html(url2) %>%
  html_nodes("[class*=subratingRow]")
nodes

ratingServiceValue <- map_df(nodes, function(node) {
  
  data.frame(rating = str_match(node%>%html_node('span')%>%html_attr('class'),'\\d+')%>%as.integer()/10,
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})
ratingServiceValue

Ubicación <- ratingServiceValue[1,]
Limpieza <- ratingServiceValue[2,]
Servicio <- ratingServiceValue[3,]
Calidad_Precio <- ratingServiceValue[4,]

HotelCategory <- TripHotel %>%
  html_nodes(".hotels-hotel-review-about-with-photos-Reviews__subratingRow--2u0CJ, ui_bubble_rating") %>%
  html_text()
HotelCategory

Estilo <- TripHotel %>%
  html_node(".hotels-hr-about-layout-TextItem__textitem--2JToc+ .hotels-hr-about-layout-TextItem__textitem--2JToc") %>%
  html_text()
Estilo

HotelsDef <- data.frame(Hotel = Hotel, 
                        Location = Location, 
                        OverallRating = OverallRating, 
                        Ubicación = Ubicación, 
                        Limpieza = Limpieza, 
                        Servicio = Servicio, 
                        Calidad_Precio = Calidad_Precio, 
                        Estilo = Estilo, 
                        TotalReviews = TotalReviews)
HotelsDef
}

#CREAMOS UN DATASET CONJUNTO

melia1 <- read_html("melia.html")

melia1 %>% 
  html_nodes(css = "a[href]") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  Filter(f = function(.) !grepl("javascript:void", .)) %>% 
  paste0("https://tripadvisor.com", .) %>% 
  cat(sep = "\n")

melia2 <- read_html("melia2.html")

melia2 %>% 
  html_nodes(css = "a[href]") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  Filter(f = function(.) !grepl("javascript:void", .)) %>% 
  paste0("https://tripadvisor.com", .) %>% 
  cat(sep = "\n")

melia3 <- read_html("melia3.html")

melia3 %>% 
  html_nodes(css = "a[href]") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  Filter(f = function(.) !grepl("javascript:void", .)) %>% 
  paste0("https://tripadvisor.com", .) %>% 
  cat(sep = "\n")

melia4 <- read_html("melia4.html")

melia4 %>% 
  html_nodes(css = "a[href]") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  Filter(f = function(.) !grepl("javascript:void", .)) %>% 
  paste0("https://tripadvisor.com", .) %>% 
  cat(sep = "\n")

  #Los unimos

  get30hotels <- function(melia1){
    data <- data.frame()
    i=1
    for(i in 1:length(melia1)){
      TripHotel <- read_html(paste0("https://www.tripadvisor.com", melia1[i]))
      HotelsDef <- getHotel(TripHotel)
      data <- rbind.fill(data, HotelsDef)
      print(i)
    }
    data
  }
  
  HOTELS <- get30hotels(melia1)
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit https://www.tripadvisor.com/Search?q=melia&geo=187427&ssrc=h&rf=1 (URL parameters selected from manual search on website)

Open browser developer tools. Go to Network tab. Refresh. Look for the data. Closest we get is
[image]

"Copy response" and save it as local html file, `melia-tripadvisor.html`.

Extract 30 links with

```
library(rvest)

doc <- read_html("melia-tripadvisor.html")

doc %>% 
  html_nodes(css = "a[href]") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  Filter(f = function(.) !grepl("javascript:void", .)) %>% 
  paste0("https://tripadvisor.com", .)
```

Next 30 links could be extracted by visiting page 2 of search results https://www.tripadvisor.com/Search?q=melia&geo=187427&ssrc=h&rf=2 (note `rf=2`) and reproducing above steps

---

Assuming 4 such HTML files have been collected, named `melia1.html`, `melia2.html`, etc.

In `getHotel`, fix `nodes <- read_html(url2) %>%` by replacing with `nodes <- TripHotel %>%`

Then

```
n_files <- 4

files <- paste0("melia", seq_len(n_files), ".html")

extract_links <- function(html_file) {
  read_html(html_file) %>%
    html_nodes(css = "a[href]") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>%
    Filter(f = function(.) !grepl("javascript:void", .)) %>%
    paste0("https://tripadvisor.com", .)
}

links <- unlist(lapply(files, extract_links))

HOTELS <- 
  links %>% 
  map(read_html) %>% 
  map_dfr(getHotel)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank u so much! I was able to get the all the URLs but I got some problems afterwards. When trying to create the data frame I get an error. Also, I am not really sure how could I create it including all the URLs. I only know how to do it for one. I copy you my code and error in the original question.

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much!! It worked. Just three more little doubts: 1- How can we make the scrapping of the hotels class bubble (stars)? 2 - Is there any way to extract from tripadvisor the lat and long? 3- In Hotel Style is it possible to get all lines (example business and family) instead of just one? And again, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: 1. Do you mean ordering the resulting data frame by rating? It can be done a posteriori, look at e.g. `dplyr::arrange`. 2. & 3. It can be done. Be aware that web scraping is a grey area, read Terms of use/Terms of service.

Comment: Hint for 2. Look for `"coords":` in page source.

Comment: great, I will try coords now. Also, I attached the image of the bubble scrapping in my original post. Also, I just realized that when putting all the files together, instead of the four pages with all the URLs we get one page four times repeated.

Comment: Make sure to grab the HTML corresponding to each page of results. Navigate between pages manually before refreshing in the network tab if necessary. This could probably be automated but it's more complicated, due to the way the website handles sessions

Comment: Great done it! Thank you! And, do you know how to do the scrapping of the bubbles of the stars? (The image attached in the original code).

Comment: Look for a `starRating` property in a JSON defined in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Hi Aurèle, I tried but still doesn´t work. I put in my original code, what we got.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the place for complex follow up questions and an extended discussion about web scraping. Let me point you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306761/ . This should be easy to adapt in R with jsonlite.